# revit Api : FacingFlipped property of FamilyInstance(door) gives different values?

Tags: revit-api, revit

I am trying to retrieve the FamilyInstance FacingFlipped

I have 2 cases

case 1: if the wall is drawn from  left to right and we place door the face flip value I get is  "False" 
[image: LeftToRight]

case 2 : if wall is drawn from right to left and we place door the face flip value i get is  "True" 
[image: LeftToRight]

does door face Flip Value Depends on the start and endPoint of wall?
On both cases wall is placed at top side of wall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Orientation is based on the FamilyInstance.Orientation property - check out the original documentation here:

http://www.revitapidocs.com/2017/a11ec72c-2498-aaea-4b2e-2adac454856c.htm

I assume that if the current direction is the same as the XYZ returned from this property FacingFlipped will return "true" as opposed to "false"